# Formatting date in french in a search bar

Tags: php

I have a table named **messages** with 4 fields which are id_message, title, date_message, fk_user.

Then I have another table named **users** with 2 fields: id_user, pseudo.

My goal is to format the date of the field **date_message** in the format french in my overview.

It's OK for this step.
Here is my request for information...

```
$requeteSQL = "SELECT messages.id_message, messages.title, DATE_FORMAT(messages.date_message,'%d/%m/%Y') 
               AS  date_message,id_user AS fk_user, users.pseudo
               FROM messages INNER JOIN users 
               ON messages.fk_user=users.id_user 
               ORDER BY id_user ASC";
```

[image]

Now my problem is that I have a search bar, when I enter a title, the date is not correct... The date is en format english.

[image]

```
if(isset($_GET['q']) AND !empty($_GET['q'])){
  $q = htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']);
  $requeteSQL = 'SELECT messages.*, users.pseudo 
                 FROM messages INNER JOIN users 
                 ON messages.fk_user=users.id_user
                 WHERE title LIKE "%' .$q.'%" ORDER BY id_message ASC';
}
```

I have tried this

```
if(isset($_GET['q']) AND !empty($_GET['q'])){
  $q = htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']);
  $requeteSQL = "SELECT messages.id_message, messages.title, DATE_FORMAT(messages.date_message,'%d/%m/%Y') 
                 AS  date_message,id_user AS fk_user, users.pseudo
                 FROM messages INNER JOIN users 
                 ON messages.fk_user=users.id_user 
                 WHERE title LIKE "%' .$q.'%" ORDER BY id_message ASC";
}
```

I have several error messages

- Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in on line 18
- Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero in on line 1
- DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero in on line 18

[image]

The line 18 is here

```
WHERE title LIKE "%' .$q.'%" ORDER BY id_message ASC";
```

I don't know the problem ?

I thank you for your help.

Comment: English dates are written dd/mm/yyyy (Eur format), American are mm/dd/yyyy (USA), Japanese (and ISO) are yyyy-mm-dd  http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. The function `htmlspecialchars()` does _not_ escape strings properly for database queries. That function is for escaping HTML to HTML entities for output, preventing XSS and similar.

Comment: I would probably format the dates on output instead of in the database query.

Comment: _Side note:_ You don't need to use both `isset()` and `!empty()` in the same `if`-condition. Just use `!empty()` since that covers the checks done by `isset()` as well.

Comment: Magnus Eriksson: Hello, thank you for your help. I wil see for SQL Injections afterward. Our teacher we have learn to do thus...

Even without isset() I alwas have the problem... It's about of the formatting in french when I tape a title in my search bar, however in english it works.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the improper SQL-escaping (see Magnus' comment) which you really need to fix, you get warnings because of the following code:

```
     //        " String opens here
 $requeteSQL = "SELECT messages.id_message, messages.title, DATE_FORMAT(messages.date_message,'%d/%m/%Y') 
             AS  date_message,id_user AS fk_user, users.pseudo
             FROM messages INNER JOIN users 
             ON messages.fk_user=users.id_user 
             WHERE title LIKE "%' .$q.'%" ORDER BY id_message ASC";
     //                       ^ String closes here
```

So your PHP looks like something as

```
"String"  %  '.$q.'  %  "String"
```

where `'.$q.'` is just another string, and `%` is the modulo operator.

Fix your string's and you fix your warning:

```
$requeteSQL = 'SELECT ... WHERE title like "%' . $q . '%" ORDER BY ...'
          //  ^ String opens                 ^ String closes
```

Comment: Hello Peter van der Wal, If I do like this `'SELECT messages.id_message, messages.title, DATE_FORMAT(messages.date_message,'%d/%m/%Y') 
                 AS messages.date_message, id_user AS fk_user, users.pseudo 
                 FROM messages INNER JOIN users 
                 ON messages.fk_user=users.id_user
                 WHERE title LIKE "%' .$q.'%" ORDER BY id_message ASC';`    I have an error message **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%' in C:\wamp64\www\test\view_message.php on line 26** my problem is here now `WHERE title LIKE "%' .$q.'%" ORDER BY id_message ASC';`

Comment: Have a look at where you close your string!

Comment: I don't understand I really sorry... I don't see the error... :-(

Comment: You open your string with `'`, now look for the first next `'`. Since you didn't escape that one, this is where you closes your string. Add a backslash before it to escape it (`\'`) or use the double quote there (since that one is also valid SQL)

Comment: @anais_stemb - If you change you query to: `"SELECT messages.id_message, messages.title, DATE_FORMAT(messages.date_message, '%d/%m/%Y') AS  date_message,id_user AS fk_user, users.pseudo FROM messages INNER JOIN users ON messages.fk_user=users.id_user WHERE title LIKE '%{$q}%' ORDER BY id_message ASC"`, the parse errors would go away (pay close attention to all the quotes). However, I _strongly_ suggest looking into parameterized prepared statements instead since it's _very_ bad using unescaped user data like this, no matter what your teacher says. It would also remove the current issue.

Comment: @ Magnus Eriksson : yesssssssssssssssss thank you a lot Magnus I was stuck since yesterday !!! I am happy thank you very much !!! :-) :-) :-)

Comment: @ Peter van der Wal: My problem was here `''%{$q}%' ` I save this thing on my notes thank you for your help. :-)